# Visibility of filtered out records in TDataSet OnFilterRecord event

Tags: delphi, c++builder

which run first, TDataSet OnFilterRecord  or OnCalcFields event? 
Are records set to Accept = false are still visible in OnCalcFields event? 
 if it is, is there a property to check record visibility?

the code situation is like, when dataset has more records like 3k, 
 OnRecordFilter has manual filter on string fields for records visibility on grid (Accept = true / false), 
OnCalckFields has extra columns lookup to other datasets, 
the function that sum the amount columns is so slow with or without filter.
when i disable the OnCalcFields event, the execution was so fast.

DataSet is TFDQuery, loaded initial data is free date range so user can view like 3 or more year date range. 
ui looks like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XyrN.png

Comment: Which TDataSet type are you using, TAdoQuery, TFDQuery, etc?  The reason I ask is that the filtering process is not actually defined in TDataSet, it is implementation-specific.  There is not usually much difference in performance between using OnFilterRecord and a string filter expression.  BUT, it is easy to do things inside then OnFilterRecord handler which impact performance negatively.  You need to add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your q, so we can see exactly what you are doing.

Comment: If you are populating the TDataSet from a query, usng a query component (like TFDQuery) and pushing the filter to the query will allow the data source to do the filtering for you - this is almost certainly going to be quicker than retrieving all of the data and filtering it yourself.

Comment: Hi MartynA, its TFDQuery, initial data loaded in dataset are in Date range - can show data in grid like 3 or 4 years records, then a FilterBox input to show only word matched records via OnRecordFilter, OnCalcFields just a lookup to some dataset like status column.

Comment: Yes Rob Lambden - its fast actually, all happens in memory client side, but when more data are loaded, i suspect OnCalcFields still reads filtered out records, like if only 3 records result on grid, all records in dataset are still being traversed - but im not 100% sure though,

Comment: Hi MartynA, does this mean filtered out records are visible in OnCalcFields? if Yes, would you happen to know what is the property or flag in dataset record that represents record visibility. i can use this to skip record in OnCalcFields.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's workaround i did to this OnCalcEvent difficulty while no exact answer to my query.

solution:
**a way to skip OnCalcEvent when traversing dataset with huge initial records loaded**

1. create a public variable
2. set value to public variable before dataset iteration
3. in OnCalcEvent, check the value to exit to abort the event code execution
4. after dataset iteration. re-set the dataset bookmark to force run the OnCalcFields event else calcFields column will be empty

it works for me, for now.

another idea is to create pagination (paging to limit query return similar to web apps) instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer will be meaningless to readers here because you have not provided any details of the context in which this code operates.  And what on Earth is the "pagination" you mention?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: its an analogy, pagination means add a paging feature in desktop app similar to web apps to limit rows query returns. my solution is simply skip the OnCalcFields event as i mentioned in my question. How come its not clear?

Answer (score 3):

You can test this for yourself.

1. Create a new VCL project and add a TFDMemTable, TDataSource, TDBGrid, TCheckBox (called cbUseFilterExpr) and TButton
   to the form.
2. Connect up the FDMemTable, TDataSource and TDBGrid as you normally would.
3. Add an OnFilterCalls integer form field and event handlers shown below.
4. Compile and run.

Code

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  AField : TField;
  i : Integer;
begin
  AField := TIntegerField.Create(Self);
  AField.FieldName := 'ID';
  AField.DataSet := FDMemTable1;

  AField := TStringField.Create(Self);
  AField.FieldName := 'Name';
  AField.DataSet := FDMemTable1;

  FDMemTable1.CreateDataSet;

  for i := 1 to 100 do
    FDMemTable1.InsertRecord([1, 'Name' + IntToStr(i)]);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OnFilterCalls := 0;

  FDMemTable1.Filtered := False;
  if cbUseFilterExpr.Checked then
     FDMemTable1.Filter := 'Name= ''Name1'''
   else
     FDMemTable1.Filter := '';
   FDMemTable1.Filtered := True;
   ShowMessage('OnFilterCalls ' + IntToStr(OnFilterCalls));
end;

procedure TForm1.FDMemTable1FilterRecord(DataSet: TDataSet;
  var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  Inc(OnFilterCalls);
end;
```

The app populates FDMemTable1 with 100 records. The OnFilterCalls variable will
count the number of times `OnFilterRecord` is called when filtering is activated.

Clicking Button1 sets a filter on FDMemTable1 which differs depending on whether
cbUseFilterExpr is checked or not:  If it is, filtering uses a filter expression which only
matches record ID=1. The result displayed by ShowMessage is 1, iow, the `OnFilterRecord`
event is called only once.  If cbUseFilterExpr is *not* checked ShowMessage displays the value 100.

Conclusion:  For FDMemTable (and, I confidently predict, other FireDAC dataset types) the `OnFilterRecord`
event is called once for each record which matches the FDMemTable's `Filter` expression, if any,
or once for each record in the dataset if the `Filter` expression is blank.  Iow, `OnFilterRecord`
is only called for records which match the Filter expression, if there is one, so it behaves as if `OnFilterRecord`
is called "after" filtering via the `Filter` expression, so the answer to your q in FireDAC's case is "No", expression-filtered records are not visible in the `OnFilterRecord` event.

As mentioned in a comment,  TDataSet does not define how a dataset processes filtering, rather it is
implementation-specific and may differ between different dataset component libraries.

**Update** You still haven't provided any details of what exactly you are doing in your code
(and on reflection your q should probably have been closed for lacking debugging details), but
I think you can satisfy yourself that what I have said above also applies to your situation.  Simply put a debugger breakpoint
on the `end` in `TForm1.FDMemTable1FilterRecord(DataSet: TDataSet`.  Run the app and  check the cbUseFilterExpr checkbox.  When the bp triggers, repeatedly single-step the debugger by pressing
`F8` until you land in the unit FireDAC.DatS, in the method `TFDDatSView.Rebuild`.  You will see that your are in a `for` loop,

```
      for i := iBegin to iEnd do begin
        ...
```

This is the loop which is executed when the filtering is applied to the dataset, once for each record in the dataset, and from the for-loop's contents
it will be a straightforward matter to satify yourself that the OnFilterRecord event is only called
for any record which is visible because it satifies any filter expression which is in effect.

Comment: Big thanks MartynA. very much appreciate your effort. Actually the filterbox in image is wrapped in class and reusable, used in many sections. i dont doubt the OnFilterRecord event (this event is in the class too). my doubt is in OnCalcFields event (not inside class) whether does it still traverse to hidden records or not. i will continue observe OnCalc event.. Thanks again MartynA

Comment: sorry i can't yet MartynA, but so much thanks for your time. i was looking how to skip OnCalcEvent recursive hurdle.